# Make Select box has a form input that can filter and search through my options with AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to turn a current select box (which currently have a lot of options) to a searchable select box, with a input inside it to make search and filtering easier.

The select box is a directive, and it's used in many places on the application.

My angular version: "angular": "1.3.20"

My bootstrap version:  "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.1"

Here's my code:

```js
.directive('mySelector', function() {
    return {
        template: '<select
                       class="form-control"
                       ng-change="$parent.reloadOtherSelector(inputIdItem, afterList)"
                       ng-model="inputIdItem"
                       ng-options=\'e.id as (e.number + " - " + e.name) for e in $parent.getItems {{angularfilter}}\'
                       ng-required={{objectRequired}}
                       ng-disabled="allowModify == false">
                           <option value="">{{ $parent.labelItem }}</option>
                   </select>',

        restrict: 'E',

        scope : { inputIdItem: '=', inputIdOther: '=', afterList: '=', objectRequired: '=', allowModify: '=', listFilter: '='},

        controller: function($scope){

            $scope.$watch("inputIdItem", function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.inputIdOther) && !angular.isUndefined(newValue) && !angular.isUndefined(oldValue))
                    $scope.inputIdOther = null;
            });

            $scope.angularfilter = $scope.listFilter ? (" | filter: " + JSON.stringify($scope.listFilter) + "") : "";
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add an autocomplete to your input.

Here is an example - https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/CU1K3O

If you not apposed to using material design there is a directive that you and add and filter your results from your html side.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete